# Move avi files to a different drive after being created using batch file

Tags: batch-file

Due to little `C:/` drive space, I have spent hours looking and trying code that will manage the following with my `X-Plane 11` `avi` files process and move.

1. `Xplane11` is creating `*.avi` files to my `C:/` drive. Each `*.avi` file is approximately 2 GB in size.
2. `Xplane11` will continue creating `*.avi` files as long as it continues to record flight.

I need a batch file which will do the following:

1. Check for `*.avi` files on `C:/` and their status.
2. Wait to complete creation **before moving** them from `C:/` drive to `D:/`. Then. move them.
3. Continue this process until simulator recording has finished and no more `*.avi` files are being created.

I have tried numerous variations of code similar to this:

```bat
@echo off

:loop
if not exist "C:\X-Plane 11\Output\*.avi" goto :end

if exist ("C:\X-Plane 11\Output\*.avi") do (

If %Errorlevel% gtr 0 (
echo Avi file still being created please wait! 
) else (
echo Avi created and is now being moved!
goto :copy
)
)
:copy
start /w "" move "C:\X-Plane 11\Output\*.avi" "D:\X-Plane 11\Output\New Captures
loop

:end
echo Avi does not exist!
exit
```

The problem I find is that it won't wait until the `*.avi` finishes before moving and preferred without any console key presses as I am not always sitting at simulator when files being created.

Comment: I'd suppose that default destination of `.avi` files changes to `"D:\X-Plane 11\Output\*.avi"` if you _reinstall_ `X-Plane 11` to disk **D:**?

Comment: Hi JosefZ. I would but my SSD C:/ contains the core XPlane 11 application and is much faster than my HDD drive unfortuntely. Thanks for the suggestion though : )

Comment: Where did you see an `If` - `Exist` - `Do` or a `Start` - `/Wait` - `Move` statement used, because I've a feeling this is my first time!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed a partial batch solution to my question having looked through previous stackoverflow solutions and help from its coders (thx Mofi). It will check for an existing .avi and move it to another directory when it has completed being created and repeat the process until no more .avi files exist at source location. I am now looking to change its name when moved as any new .avi files overwrite the previous.

Here is my new code so far....

```
@echo off

:loop


if not exist "C:\X-Plane 11\Output\*.avi" (
echo No more Avi files to move! 
echo Will now Exit!
pause
goto :exit
)
) else (
if "!errorlevel!" GTR "0" (
echo
) else (
echo Please Wait.....
for %%F in (C:\X-Plane 11\Output\*.avi) do (
move "C:\X-Plane 11\Output\*.avi" "D:\X-Plane 11\Output\"
)   

PING localhost -n 10 >NUL   
goto :loop
)
)
)
)
:exit
exit
```